# How do I configure AWS Amplify to use a custom docker image that I was able to upload to my aws ecr?

Tags: docker, create-react-app, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, amazon-ecr

I am trying to get away from the AWS linux 2 image for the build on AWS Amplify because node version has become an issue. Thus, I created a docker image for both developers to use, which runs  locally perfectly. I was able to upload it to our private repository on AWS and wanted to use it to run the react app we are we working to develop.

The issue is during the provision step of aws amplify we are getting

```
"\[BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container image. CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for XXXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-X.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXX, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXX:assumed-role/AemiliaCo\]
```

Here was our yml file:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
       image
    build:
      commands:
       setup
  artifacts:
  cache:
    

 hosting
custom:
  hosting:
    container:
      domain: customdomain.com  
      image: XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-X.amazonaws.com/XXXXXX:latest 
      skipBuild: true
```

How do we overcome this? We do not want to push it to a public ecr repository because our code base will be exposed. However, we are relying on the aws amplify pro's of auth etc to our app that that speaks our backend also setup through the aws amplify console.

The service role on the aws amplify app will not allow us to apply other aws policies to it besides amplify related ones.

Comment: 'may require 'docker login' - googling 'ECR docker login', 2nd result is what you're looking for: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html